# Attacking someone that is using the Ring

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

The person holding the ring was being attacked by a werewolf. They claimed that since they were holding the Ring, the werewolf and the hero have to roll for Sanity instead of Might. I thought that since the werewolf was attacking, they roll for Might, since that is the trait the werewolf is attacking with? Is this correct? Would the dice roll be for sanity or for might?

Comment: You should break this up into 3 different posts since you have 3 different questions that will get 3 different answers,

Comment: Since you didn't repost your additional questions, I posted #3 [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/39210/2880). #2 is too simple: You gotta follow the instructions the game give you. Immediately.

Answer (score 4):

You were correct; the attacker determines the stat used.

---

The Ring reads:

> If you attack an opponent that has a Sanity trait, you can attack with Sanity instead of Might.

As it states, one can only use the Ring when taking the attack action. If someone is merely the subject of an attack, they may not use the Ring.

As usual, the attacker determines the stat used for both the attack and the defense. In this case, Might is used by both the attacker and the defender.

Comment: Preferred over the other answer because it explicitly mentions that the type of attack always determines the type of defense - it's not a special interaction of/with the ring.

Comment: As a side note it should also be mentioned that you can only attack with the stat if both the attacker and defender has that stat. While it does not matter in this case but if you where attacking a monster that didn't have sanity you could not use the ring to attack them.

Comment: @Joe W, This question is not about what can be attacked with the Ring, and that limitation is already mentioned in the Ring itself.

Comment: It was more a statement about attacking in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the Ring when attacking.  If you are being attacked, use whichever stat the other character is attacking you with (usually Might, unless they have a special attack of their own)